# "One" as pronoun in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, pronouns

How can we express the pronoun "one" in Latin when it's impersonal or indefinite?
Any example: "what's your house? The white one"
I know that we can use "is qui" when way say "the one who..." but is there an specific word for "one" with that meaning, or we just use the adjective?

Comment: Hi Antônio, this question appears to be a near-duplicate. I think the answer in the linked question should also provide an answer for you here. If you don't find that your questions has been answered in full, feel free to edit your question indicating what you're still confused and we can open the question back up then. Ping me (by typing "@cmw" at the start of your comment) if you have concerns about this process or are unsure of what to do.

Comment: @cmt that helped me.

Comment: Great and welcome! I hope you stick around and ask more Latin questions!